# React firebase sign out

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have this code:

```
const signOutUser = () => firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
    //Sign out
}).catch(function (error) {
    alert(error)
});
```

The signOut method is supposed to redirect by its own or I have to code it?

Comment: you will need to write the redirect code as well as clearing any other session-related data, if any.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Chilarai :)